# CKEditor and Font Color saved but not working

Tags: colors, save, ckeditor, fckeditor

I've just installed CKEditor and call it with JS tag.
When I save the text, all the font attributes (indentation, space, size, decoration,etc.) are correctly saved .

The problem is that when I want to edit the data, with CKEditor, all these attributes are well loaded but the COLOR even if, in the example below, it's set to "BLUE"!

Which is very bizarre because when I can see the color style property in my database:

```
<h3 style=\"\\&quot;color:blue\\&quot;\">
<strong>aulne </strong>kjhqsdf <span style=\"\\&quot;color:#008000;\\&quot;\"><u>kjhkjsdfh </u></span>j&#39;<span style=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\"><em>esp&egrave;re </em></span><span style=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\">bien<sup>2</sup></span></h3>
```

I found this old bug post http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/116
where no solution is found.

Thank very much,
regards.

Comment: Your CSS looks broken with all the slashes and quotes in it - I would except it not to work. What code exactly are you using to set up the editor and fill it with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
on the php side, before inserting, I was using the "addslash" function I forgot to remove.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It stopped working when I commented out the stripslashes from the php code. So I was doing the opposite and not stripping the slashes. Once I read the other answer I thought dah, I commented the following out yesterday. Now works fine! Certain PHP modes like safe mode will generate extra slashes to lessen hack attempts so moving code from servers with different modes can cause issues. So this answer is the same but opposite reason. My server is in safe mode so it automatically adds the slashes and I must remove them.

$a10 = stripslashes($a10);